# What does "YA" "A" mean in inline assembly

Tags: c, assembly

This is inline assembly code at my workplace:

```
 static __inline__ int16 mulI16_I16byI16RndDiv64(int16 a, int16 b) //

 {

 int16 result;
 int16 result2;    /* clobbering of the register */
 __asm__ __volatile__ (
      "muls YA, A, %w3\n\t"
      "add YA, #32\n\t"
      "asr YA, #6\n\t"
      "adc A, #0"
      : "=a" (result), "=y" (result2)
      : "%a" (a), "r" (b)
      );

 return result;
 }
```

What does `YA`, `A` mean?

Here is the code of a typical example.
Generally, it seems to use `%0 %1` to store input and output.

```
int src = 1;
int dst;   

asm ("mov %1, %0\n\t"
    "add $1, %0"
    : "=r" (dst) 
    : "r" (src));

 printf("%d\n", dst);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you know who at your workplace wrote the code? Did you try asking the author? Do you have any other familiarity with assembly language? If `adc` is confusing to you, why are `add`, `muls` and `asr` not confusing?

Comment: You didn't specify the processor architecture, but I would assume that `Y` and `A` are registers and `YA` is a register pair with `Y` holding the high word and `A` holding the low word. Some of these instructions seem to operate on a register pair by design and so `Y` gets clobbered even though its contents are ignored at the end. You can see that here the `A` and `Y` registers were specifically selected instead of just `"r"` where the compiler would decide, that's why `%0`, `%1` also isn't used. `adc` is probably "add with carry". To know more, we'd need to know the processor architecture!

Comment: The assembler might be case insensitive. The line `"=a" (result), "=y" (result2)` specifies the registers used for the two variables. I guess `Y` and `A` refer to these registers.

Comment: if  Y and A refer to y and a   what does mean YA ??

Comment: I don't recognize those register names.  Use `gcc -v` to see an architecture name.  It's not x86, ARM, AArch64, PowerPC, or anything else I recognize.  If we knew a name for the architecture, we could google for you and find out the answer to your question.  But very likely CherryDT is right that it's a pair of registers treated as a single integer twice as wide, that you can use with arithmetic right shift for example.

Comment: What processor are you using? Is it some ARM variant?

Comment: What architecture are you programming for?

Comment: Skimming https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html#Machine-Constraints doesn't reveal any obvious matches.  Are you using a stock version of gcc, or some customized fork, or some other compiler that supports gcc-like asm?

Comment: @NateEldredge I searched through that page for like 20 minutes yesterday really trying to find out what this is out of curiosity. I wonder where the OP has gone, but doesn't this look too similar to ARM? Maybe it's some ARM variant used in a closed environment, but I don't know if such thing can exist considering ARM's licensing.